# Isomorphism and GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are two finite groups such that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}\cong\frac{H}{Z(H)}$. The Command $K:=IsomorphismGroups(\frac{G}{Z(G)},\frac{H}{Z(H)})$, in GAP, gives all the isomorphism from $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ onto $\frac{H}{Z(H)}$. I have two questions:-

1. If $\chi\in K$, then how to apply the map $\chi$ on any element $x\in \frac{G}{Z(G)}$ in GAP? I have tried $\chi(x)$ and $x^\chi$, both are not working. I have not seen anything like this as well in the GAP manual.
2. Suppose $\chi(gZ(G))=y$. Then $y=hZ(H)$ for some $h\in H$. How to extract the element $h$ in $y$ in GAP?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off, let me correct you on `IsomorphismGroups`. It does not give you *all* isomorphisms, but rather it gives you *one* isomorphism (if it exists, otherwise it returns `fail`).

```
gap> G := Group( [ (2,8)(3,7)(5,6), (1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8) ] );;
gap> H := QuaternionGroup( 16 );;
gap> p := NaturalHomomorphismByNormalSubgroup( G, Centre( G ) );;
gap> pG := Image( p );;
gap> q := NaturalHomomorphismByNormalSubgroup( H, Centre( H ) );;
gap> qH := Image( q );;

gap> K := IsomorphismGroups( pG, qH );
[ f1, f2, f3 ] -> [ f2, f1*f2, f1*f2*f3 ]
```

Of course, if you have one isomorphism, you can calculate the automorphism group of either the source or range group, and compose with the previously mentioned isomorphism.

As for your questions:

1. Since you didn't provide any example code, I'm not sure what went wrong, but both things you mentioned should work. They are mentioned under [32.4-6 Image](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap32_mj.html#X87F4D35A826599C6).

```
gap> pg := Random( pG );
f2
gap> K(pg);
f1*f2
gap> pg^K;
f1*f2
```

You could also use the other commands mentioned in [the same section](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap32_mj.html#X83B4FF15847F06FC) of the GAP manual:

```
gap> ImagesRepresentative( K, pg );
f1*f2
gap> ImageElm( K, pg );
f1*f2
gap> Image( K, pg );
f1*f2
```

2. In thise case, you will want to use `PreImagesRepresentative` ([32.5-4](https://docs.gap-system.org/doc/ref/chap32_mj.html#X7AE24A1586B7DE79)).

```
gap> qh := pg^K;
f1*f2
gap> h := PreImagesRepresentative( q, qh );
x*y
gap> h in H;
true
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking that IsomorphismGroups(G,H) gives all the isomorphisms from G to H. Now you have clear my doubt. Lastly, if you can help, what is the command to gives all the isomorphisms from a group $G$ to a Group $H$?

Comment: K(pg); and  pg^K; does not work for me. I dont know why. So i use Image( K, pg );. Thank you once agian.

Comment: @D.N. For your first question: like I mentioned, compose the automorphism group with the isomorphism you found. In the example I posted, `List( AutomorphismGroup( pG ), aut -> aut * K )` should give you the list of all isomorphisms from `pG` to `pH`. As for the second question, this question seems more suitable for the [GAP forum](https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html) than here on MSE. You would likely have to provide some information on your GAP installation and the exact code you are trying to run.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.